# Is normalization a form of marginalization?

Tags: bayesian, normalization, marginal-distribution

Is it correct to say that computing the **partition function** is equivalent to **marginalizing** the distribution (over all of its variables)?

Motivation:
[Yann Lecun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yann_LeCun) [said recently](https://twitter.com/ylecun/status/1203817641942503424?s=20):

> I like free energies. 
>   Which means I like marginalization. 
>   What I don't like is normalization. 
>   I'm a probability-free Bayesian, 
>   AKA an aspiring statistical physicist.

[as well as](https://twitter.com/ylecun/status/1203816915258335232?s=20):

> I don't like normalizing, but I don't mind marginalizing.

But isn't **normalization** a type of **marginalization**?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing what Lecun means is the computation of 
$$
\int L(x^n\vert \theta)\pi(d\theta)
$$
Where $L(x^n\vert \theta)$ is the likelihood of a sample $x^n$ ( or $\exp(U(x^n))$ if you think of energy) the marginal likelihood which can be used as a free energy or likelihood of itself. The normalization constant that is needed to make
$$
L(x^n\vert \theta)\pi(d\theta)
$$
A probability is its inverse (not always a trivial operation in particular you lose unbiasedness of vanilla Monte Carlo alg. Of the first integral). The later is needed for Bayesian statistics (at least formally as it's computation can be avoided through MCMC)

Comment: Thanks @aros. Not sure I fully follow though. In your comment above you said _"$(x_n|)$  is the likelihood of a sample $x^n$  the marginal likelihood.."_ (maybe it's a typo? i.e. is $L$ here the likelihood *or* the marginal likelihood?). Also, not sure what you mean by "A probability is its inverse". I guess you mean that in order to make  $L(x^n\vert \theta)\pi(d\theta)$ a probability you need to compute  $\frac{1}{\int L(x^n\vert \theta)\pi(d\theta)}$?. Finally, to connect this back to my Q, do you think the answer is yes? ("normalization is a form of marginalization?")

Comment: $L(x^n\vert\theta)$ is the likelihood in my notations. But this likelihood could depend on additional parameters $L(x^n\vert \theta,\beta)$ for instance then $m(x^n\vert \beta)=\int L(x^n\vert \theta,\beta)\pi(d\theta)$ would be the marginal likelihood of parameter beta (you could do maximum likelihood to find an estimator of\beta). Regarding the original question Would say marginalisation is needed for normalisation. But it is something more